# Measureability of Simple Functions over different sets.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Suppose E and F are subsets of R (we do not know yet whether E and F are Lebesgue measurable). Suppose we also know the function $s(x) = 5\chi_{E} (x) + 2\chi_{F} (x)

is Lebesgue measurable. Prove that under the previous conditions E and F are Lebesgue measurable sets.

Edit: As an attempt at a solution I broke up s(x) into four cases, one where x is a member of both E and F, one where x is only in E and one where x is only in F and tried to show each case was measurable. The second two are trivial however I am having trouble proving the first case. (Also if anyone could help with LaTex I'm a bit new at trying to post stuff like that)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The fact that your function $s(x)$ is measurable means that for any measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $s^{-1}(A)$ is a measurable set.

What does your function $s$ look like?  We have
$$
s(x)=\begin{cases}7 & \text{if }x\in E\cap F\\ 5 & \text{if }x\in E\setminus F\\ 2 & \text{if }x\in F\setminus E\\ 0 & \text{if }x\notin E\cup F\end{cases}
$$
Can you use this, and measurability of $s$, to show that $E\cap F$, $E\setminus F$, and $F\setminus E$ are measurable?  Try finding a measurable set (and, in fact, a pretty nice one) $A$ such that $s^{-1}(A)=E\cap F$, or $E\setminus F$, or $F\setminus E$.

Can you finish the argument from there?